# STM32 programmer pin configuration

Tags: stm32, programmer, swd

I have a ST-LINK V2 programmer for STM8 and STM32 with this pin configuration:

```
1-RST    2-SWCLK
3-SWIM   4-SWDIO
5-GND    6-GND
7-3.3V   8-3.3V
9-5.0V   10-5.0V
```

But on my custom board including STM32, the board pins are:

```
1-3.3V   2-SWDIO
3-GND    3-SWCLK
5-GND    6-SWO
7-NC     8-NC
9-GND    10-NRST
```

Are they two different protocols?

If it is possible to connect them, which pins should I connect to which?

Is NRST the negate of RST?

[image: ST-Link V2]

Answer (score 2):

That is not a genuine ST-Link V2 made by ST. It is a clone product with just different pinout. It may not be upgradeable or fully compatible.

And the pinout does not matter, you use the pins you need.

The real difference is on your clone the 5V and 3.3V are outputs, and on a real product, there is no 5V and 3V3 outputs, and the module needs supply voltage from target board.